# В каком роде следует писать название клавиш Shift, Ctrl и т. д?

Tags: переводы, род, существительные, компьютеры

Как правильнее написать — «Левый Shift», «Левый Alt», «Левый Ctrl», или  «Левая Shift», «Левая Alt» и «Левая Ctrl»? Первый вариант звучит лучше, но всё-таки слово «клавиша» женского рода.

Фразы используются в контексте настройки клавиатуры ПК.

Comment: Ни разу не слышал, чтобы в женском роде говорили.

Comment: Артем, в интернете встречаются оба варианта. Но в большинстве случаев м.р.

Comment: Разве функция не едина для левых и правых? Партитуру пишете?

Comment: shampar, какая функция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта. Однако, если в ближайшем контексте используется слово "клавиша", в этом случае согласование должно идти по женскому роду, чтобы было ясно, что  Shift - эта клавиша.

Answer (score 3):

... предположу, что в мужском роде, так как названные англицизмы на согласный заканчиваются и при согласовании прилагательное стоит в мужском роде... 
а если со словом *клавиша* согласовывать, то соответственно женский род...

Comment: В итоге я так и сделал: «Правая клавиша Alt, Shift и правый Alt вместе работают как Multi_Key».

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю в чем загвоздка. Как больше нравится - так и пишите(говорите). Я бы (если бы писал аппликатуру) формулировал так: "shift справа", или "клавиша shift справа". Хотя функционально разницы нет - справа или слева.